# javascript String to associative object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am just wondering if there is an easy way to create an associative object from a string that needs double split, thisstring is the result from an api call, so length of the object could change.

For instance, if I have a string that looks like this:

```
var infoValue = 'Loan Date~Loan Number~Loan Amount|15/03/2016~1042~620|15/03/2016~1044~372';
```

I want to have an object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Loan Date":"15/03/2016",
        "Loan Number":"1042",
        "Loan Amount":"620",

    },
    {
        "Loan Date":"15/03/2016",
        "Loan Number":"1042",
        "Loan Amount":"620",

    }
]
```

What I am doing right now is something like

```
var res = infoValue.split("|"); 
var activeLoans = new Array();
for(field in res) {
    if(res[field] != ''){
        activeLoans.push(res[field]);
    }
}

for(field in activeLoans){
    var row = activeLoans[field];
    rowSplit = row.split("~");
}
```

But I am not happy with this approach, as I need to create a table to display this data, and the site that I am getting this api might change the order of the response of the string, or might add other values

Comment: I don't know how to write code that will still work if the input format changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is about all you can do, though I would not use for..in for a typical array. You should be able to deal with any sequence of values, as long as the header is consistent with the rest of the data, e.g.

```js
var infoValue = 'Loan Date~Loan Number~Loan Amount|15/03/2016~1042~620|15/03/2016~1044~372';

function parseInfoValue(s) { 
  var b = s.split('|');
  var header = b.shift().split('~');
  return b.reduce(function(acc, data) {
    var c = data.split('~');
    var obj = {};
    c.forEach(function(value, i){
      obj[header[i]] = value;
    })
    acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
  },[]);
}

var x = parseInfoValue(infoValue);

document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
```

This will create the required structure no matter how many items are in each record, it just needs a label for each item in the header part and a value for each item (perhaps empty) in every data part.

#### Edit

Thinking on it a bit more, I don't know why I used *forEach* internally when *reduce* is the obvious candidate:

```js
var infoValue = 'Loan Date~Loan Number~Loan Amount|15/03/2016~1042~620|15/03/2016~1044~372';

function parseInfoValue(s) { 
  var b = s.split('|');
  var header = b.shift().split('~');
  return b.reduce(function(acc, data) {
    acc.push(data.split('~').reduce(function(obj, value, i) {
      obj[header[i]] = value;
      return obj;
    }, {}));
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

var x = parseInfoValue(infoValue);

document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
```